# Populating form using AJAX call and JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to populate form fields using an AJAX call to a php script which returns JSON data. I've tried two methods but neither work and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something entirely... I've never used AJAX before and I'm finding it confusing.

```
  $("#loadDefault").click(function()
  {      

     $.getJSON('formdata.php', {act : 'default'},
     function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value);
        })
     });
        /* function populate(frm, data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value);
            });
        }

        populate('#myForm', $.parseJSON(data)); */



    return false;
  });
```

Here is the HTML form for reference: __________________________________________________

```
<form id="myForm">

Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> <br>

Postal Code: <input type="text" id="postal" name="postal"> <br>

Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"> <br>

Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address"> <br>

<input type="submit">

</form>

<a id="loadDefault" href="">Load Default Data</a> 
<br>
```

Note: I'm not looking for someone to write the solution for me, I'm just hoping for some guidance or some idea as to what I'm missing or doing incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: can you add the json response?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `frm` is not defined.
2. Also `frm` doesn't need to be in `$('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value);` cause you only need to updated the field values.

I know you didn't want me to write the solution, but it's just your approach is correct. It's just small details you've missed.

Basically, if your response is like `{'name': 'foo', 'postal': 'bar'}`, the js should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at this view engine: https://jocapc.github.io/jquery-view-engine/ It enables you to load JSON object from the AJAX response directly into the form if properties of the object match elements of the form. You code would look like:

```
  $("#loadDefault").click(function()
  {      
     $.getJSON('formdata.php', {act : 'default', dataType: 'json'},
     function(data) {
        $('#myForm').view(data);
     });
    return false;
  });
```